# Program giving 0s as output (C++)

Tags: c++

I wrote the following program to generate the first 1000 primes, but I'm only getting 0's as output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
bool p = false;
bool is_prime(int i)
{
    int limit = sqrt(i);
    if (i == 2)
        p = true;
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
        p = false;
    else
    {
        for (int n = 3; n <= limit; n += 2)
        {
            if (i % n == 0)
            p = false;
            else
            {
                p = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

vector<int> generate_primes(int x)
{
    vector<int> Sieve;
    for (int q = 2; q <= x; q += 1)
    {
        if (is_prime(q) == true)
            Sieve.push_back(q);
    }
    return Sieve;
}

int main()
{
    for (int g = 1; g <= 1000; g += 1)
    {
        vector<int> generate_primes(7919);
        cout << generate_primes.at(g);
    }
}
```

Obviously the build is succeeding, but why am I getting an incorrect output? It looks like generate_primes is generating an empty vector, so my guess is that the problem is somewhere in that function, but I can't seem to find a problem in my code.

Comment: That's not a sieve at all.

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through a small prime line by line.

Comment: @chris: That might be ineffective, depending on where he puts his breakpoint ;)

Comment: @BenVoigt, True, but the need will arise when the function *is* called, as there is a bug in there.

Comment: @chris: You are of course referring to the foolish adherence to the "single point of return", combined with overwriting the desired value in later loop iterations?

Comment: I would advise instead of stepping through with a debugger he think carefully about what he is attempting to do. Write it out possibly. Working with what he has right now, I would argue is non-optimal. @Brandon: Sorry if this sounds harsh, but you should really consider doing this to benefit yourself as a computer scientist.

Comment: okay, I'll rethink my program and probably rewrite it; from reading the comments I think you are probably right.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Yes, and returning early would certainly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the declaration of a new variable named `generate_primes`

```
vector<int> generate_primes(7919);
```

The variable will hide the function using the same name in a larger scope.

What you wanted was a call to the function you already created, perhaps:

```
vector<int> primes_list;
generate_primes(7919).swap(primes_list);
```

Since C++11, it's just as efficient to use move initialization:

```
vector<int> primes_list = generate_primes(7919);
```

You would also be well advised to do that outside the loop... right now your prime printing program is about the slowest imaginable (at least, of those that actually do make progress).

Comment: thanks for the help, after fixing this I ran into another problem; xcode highlights the "int limit = sqrt(i);" line and has a message "Thread 1: breakpoint 1, 1", what is wrong with the program now?

Comment: @Brandon: A breakpoint is not a *problem*, it is an essential part of debugging.  Did you add the breakpoint?

Comment: Since I'm not sure what a breakpoint is, I'm pretty sure that I didn't add one, but xcode might have automatically done so?

Comment: @Brandon If you click to the left of a line of code, you can add a breakpoint. It's not too uncommon to accidentally add one, which is probably what happened. You can remove a breakpoint by control clicking it and selecting "Delete breakpoint".

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 vector<int> generate_primes(7919);
```

Is only generating a variable called `generate_primes` with the default size 7919.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

The function is not called.